# Assign Global variable from Asynctask android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a global variable:-

```
public static List<Stuff> myFinalList = new ArrayList<Stuff>();
```

I am executing certain code in my AsyncTask and want to assign the result to this 'myFinalList'.

Here is my code:-

```
private class GetList extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<News>> {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Stuff> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        myFinalList = result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<News> doInBackground(String... params) {
        //some JSON parsing
        myList.add(new Stuff(title, description));
        return myList;
    }
}
```

main.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        items = new FetchItems().execute(registerContet).get();
        new GetList().execute(items).get();
        if (myFinalList.size() == 0)    {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(Home.this)
                .setTitle("Something went wrong!")
                .setMessage("")
                .setNegativeButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                        // do nothing
                    }
                 })
            .show();
        }
        Map<String, String> idToColorMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        int colorIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < myFinalList.size(); i++) {
            //do SOme stuff  
        }
    }
    catch (...) { ... }
}
```

I tried assigning `myFinalList` from `onPostExecute()`, but back in `onCreate()` when I try to access `myFinalList` I get its value as `null`.

How can I do it?

Comment: Where are you calling the AsyncTask? Post that code. AsyncTask is asynchronous, so the part of the code after calling the AsyncTask will be executed without waiting for the results from AsyncTask. So whatever you want to do with `myFinalList` in `onCreate()`, do it in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: Both the classes are in same file? Or different?

Comment: Please post the correct code if you need help. There's a `catch` block without `try`.

Comment: Whatever you're doing in `onCreate()` with that list, do it in `onPost` because `onPost` has access to UI.

Comment: @Aniruddha both classes are in same file

Answer (score 0):

If both the classes are in same file, then you can do something like below. And use of `get` method is not preferred as it blocks the UI thread.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        try 
        {
            items = new FetchItems().execute(registerContet); // i don't know what is this line
            new GetList().execute(items); // this will call the AsyncTask
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }

  private class GetList extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<News>>
   {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Stuff> result) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        myFinalList = result;
         // here yo can access your list and this method has access to UI
        for (int i = 0; i < myFinalList.size(); i++) {
        //do SOme stuff  
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<News> doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //some JSON parsing
      myList.add(new Stuff(title, description));
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return myList;
    }
```